# Null Pointer Exception when Setting View's Color

Tags: java, android, view, nullpointerexception

I am trying to set the background of a view to red, just to try something. I added a view to the activity layout and gave it an id, "gradientView". In my Java code I create a new view like this:

```
    View gradientView = (View) findViewById(R.id.gradientView);
```

and in onCreate I do this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clean_weather);
    gradientView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

For some reason it gives me a Null Pointer Exception at findViewById. I thought I made it "not null" when I referenced it to my XML's view?!

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to initialize and declare your "gradientView" as a global member, that won't work. You can declare it but the initialization has to be done after you've set the contentview.

Answer (score 3):

Your `findviewById` should come after `setContentView(..)`;

Example:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clean_weather);
    View gradientView = (View) findViewById(R.id.gradientView);
    gradientView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Otherwise `gradientView` will be null and any operation on `null` reference results in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Please change your example to call `setBackgroundColor()` *after* `findViewById()`, otherwise NPE too.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  An implicit call to `findViewById` as opposed to `someOtherView.findViewById` will use the context of the current layout (aka, `this`).  Although, you need to first set the layout by using the `setContentView` or it won't have any XML to search though.

Comment: Why does it make it null if you call it before the setContentView() ?

Comment: refr mrres comment. it explains well.